# R - Readxl : Importing my dataset as a matrix and not a data frame anymore

Tags: r, matrix, readxl

Is it possible to use the read_excel() function and not having my dataset (which is a matrix) loaded as a data frame by default ? Here is my code :

```
library(readxl)
mobib_df <- read_excel("mobib_data.xlsx")

str(mobib_df)

tibble [13 x 8] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Origine voyageurs: chr [1:13] "Belgica" "Pannenhuis" "Bockstael" "Stuyvenbergh" ...
 $ Belgica          : num [1:13] NA 131 521 111 97 70 136 130 209 126 ...
 $ Pannenhuis       : num [1:13] 160 NA 287 147 187 54 119 73 115 83 ...
 $ Bockstael        : num [1:13] 495 335 NA 532 742 113 820 433 356 175 ...
 $ Stuyvenbergh     : num [1:13] 104 150 451 NA 134 21 149 58 90 56 ...
 $ Houba-Brugmann   : num [1:13] 73 172 718 122 NA 61 313 157 108 86 ...
 $ Heysel           : num [1:13] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 3120 NA NA ...
 $ Roi Baudouin     : num [1:13] 104 75 634 144 257 90 260 118 167 84 ...

mobib_matrix <- as.matrix(sapply(mobib_df[,-1], as.numeric))
row.names(mobib_matrix) <- as.matrix(mobib_df[,1])
```

How can I simply notify to R that my Excel file contains a matrix and not a data frame, please ?

Thank you !

Comment: What is this line `as.matrix(sapply(mobib_df[,-1], as.numeric))` doing?  You are converting to `numeric` by looping with `sapply` and `sapply` returns a `matrix`

Comment: It is converting my data frame without the row names as a numeric matrix.

Comment: Can you show the `str(mobid_df)` and update your post

Comment: I've updated the post with str(mobib_df) @akrun !

Comment: That is a `data.frame/tibble` as intended

Comment: There is a `read.matrix` from `tseries`, but it is not intended for excel data